# Replacing existing UIWebView with another

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview

I have an `NSMutableArray` of `UIWebViews`. On demand I would like to show the user the selected `UIWebView`.

This is what I have so far.

```
//Getting previously stored UIWebView from NSMutableArray
UIWebView *retrievedwebView = [helper GetWebViewByTargetURL:targetURL:webViews];

//Assigning to webview
self.webView = retrievedwebView;

//Adding a subview 
[self.view addSubview:self.webView];
```

Answer (score 3):

And why don't you have only on webview and an array of string to load?

And each time you need to update display, you simply load the new string:

```
[self.webview loadHTMLString:[arrayOfHTMLString objectAtIndex:myIndex] baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: I want the user to return back exactly where he/she left when navigating away from the UIWebView. This approach means the page will get reloaded right?

Answer (score 0):

You would also have to remove the old one, and load the URL in the newly added `UIWebView`

```
UIWebView *retrievedwebView = [helper GetWebViewByTargetURL:targetURL:webViews];
[self.webView removeFromSuperview];
self.webView = retrievedwebView;
[self.view addSubview:self.webView];
[self.webView loadHTMLString:@"http://something.com" baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: That solution ends up loading http://something.com in my UIWebView. I am wanting to show the user a previously stored UIWebView.

Comment: You didn't literally put "something.com" in your code, right? Btw, @Y.Bonafons' answer is better, choose that one.

Comment: Of course not, but I referred to something.com as it what is stated above in your solution.